# Can't get AJAX call returned data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't get the returned data of an GET AJAX call.
The call gets the data properly but I can't get the data I need in a variable and return it.

I know that the AJAX calls are asynchronous and I've tried different approaches but failed.

```
   function getQuantity(Id) {
        var productQuantity = null;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Product/ProductData/" + Id,
            success: function (response) {
                productQuantity = response.QuantityInStock;
                console.log("in call: ", productQuantity);
            }
        });
        console.log("in return: ", productQuantity);

        return productQuantity;
   }
```

**This is what I get in the console:**

in return:  null

in call:  2724 -> this is the right value

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the AJAX call and add `asycn: false` option

```
function getQuantity(Id) {
        var productQuantity = null;
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            url: "/Product/ProductData/" + Id,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("response:  ", response);
            }
        }).responseText;
   }
```

Comment: @AlonEitan from 3 years I am not using jQuery at all

Comment: @AlonEitan go do better than me and explain him how to use callbacks, promises and async/await

Comment: It's all there in the duplicate, this is very common question on SO and I see it being asked almost every day

Comment: @AlonEitan yes, you're right, just when it comes to old technologies everything nowadays is actually a duplicate of some SO question. And note that he is not asking "How to do AJAX calls", but his question is more like "Come solve my problem, because I am junior and my senior is gonna hit me if I ask him another basic question" :D